# How can an Electron app send and receive messages from Chrome browser extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, electron

I want to build a bookmark application that is based on Electron + Angular. The application will be a local desktop application. I want to synchronize Chrome bookmarks with the Electron Desktop app. I've already implemented chrome bookmarks parsing i.e export then import but I want whenever a new bookmark is added this to be synchronized with the Desktop App. An extension can be developed to do this but how exactly messaging between chrome and other apps is done?

Comment: You could run a local server and communicate through an API. Whenever a new bookmark is created, call the API `localhost:3333/addBookmark` or whatever to register it in the app.

Comment: good suggestion